# Android - Best practices for uploading images to the server

Tags: android

I have some code that sends string bytes to the server then in mvc c# i take these string bytes convert it into raw bytes and then save the bytes to file. This works great but the problem when i am sending 4 images of string bytes inside of HttpURLConnection the mvc server comes back with saying File Not Found Exception.

So i found out when i sent large images it would fail with this exception, and when i sent images lower that 3080000 bytes it sent the images and saved them to the server.

So now im deciding to show a message to the user displaying a dialog box about the file limit, is this good to do?

This is my code:

### Client

```
try {

            if (imgS!=null && imgS.size()>0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < imgS.size(); i++) {

                    if(i == 0){
                        image1 = Base64.encodeToString(imgS.get(i).bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    }
                    if(i == 1){
                        image2 = Base64.encodeToString(imgS.get(i).bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    }
                    if(i == 2){
                        image3 = Base64.encodeToString(imgS.get(i).bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    }
                    if(i == 3){
                        image4 = Base64.encodeToString(imgS.get(i).bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    }
                }
            }


            if (!isDelivered) {
                deliveredId = 2;
            }


            if (params[0] != null && (params[0].equals("0.00") || !params[0].equals(""))) {
                priceTmp = Double.valueOf(params[0]);
            }

            if (params[6] != null && (params[6].equals("0.00") || !params[6].equals(""))) {
                postageTmp = Double.valueOf(params[6]);
            }
            String responseText = "";

            SharedPreferences preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String json = String.format("{\"p_u_id\": \"%s\",\"price\": \"%.2f\"," +
                            "\"title\": \"%s\"" +
                            ",\"description\": \"%s\",\"category\": \"%d\",\"tags\": \"%s\"" +
                            ",\"image1\": \"%s\",\"image2\": \"%s\",\"image3\": \"%s\",\"image4\": \"%s\"" +
                            ",\"postcode\": \"%s\",\"postage\": \"%.2f\",\"isDelivered\": \"%d\"}",
                    preferences.getString("userId", "0"),
                    priceTmp,
                    params[1],
                    params[2],
                    selectedCategory,
                    params[4],
                    image1,
                    image2,
                    "",
                    "",
                    params[5],
                    postageTmp,
                    deliveredId
            );

            long b = image1.getBytes().length + image2.getBytes().length +image3.getBytes().length + image4.getBytes().length;
            if(b > 3080000){


                return "FileLimit";

            }else{


                URL url = new URL("http://xxx/Home/xxxx");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");      // have tried without this
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", json.getBytes().length + "");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                os.close();

                conn.connect();

                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                //here we read and print the response send by server; assuming that response type is text/html (MIME Type)
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int ch;
                //-1: end of stream
                while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) ch);
                }
                responseText = sb.toString();

                conn.disconnect();
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseText);
                pid = obj.getInt("id");
                serverImage1 = obj.getString("image1");
                serverImage2 = obj.getString("image2");


                json = String.format("{\"p_id\": \"%d\",\"image1\": \"%s\"," +
                                "\"image2\": \"%s\",\"p_u_id\": \"%s\"}",
                        pid,
                        image3,
                        image4,
                        preferences.getString("userId", "0")

                );

                url = new URL("http://xxx/Home/xxxx");
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");      // have tried without this
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", json.getBytes().length + "");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                os = conn.getOutputStream();
                os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                os.close();

                conn.connect();

                is = conn.getInputStream();
                //here we read and print the response send by server; assuming that response type is text/html (MIME Type)
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                ch = 0;
                //-1: end of stream
                while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                    sb.append((char) ch);
                }

                responseText = sb.toString();
                return responseText;
            }




        } catch (Exception e) {
            int i = 0;
        }
```

What i have done here is send the first two images to the server then send the next two images after the first two images were sent. This was funny because still if i send images two big the server will come back with an exception again.

So is it good to show a message to the user about file limit?

And how do other apps like shpock n Ebay work when they allow mulitple file uploads?

I tried using some Android Libraries but was unsusseccful.

Would like to know a way of sending maxiumum of four files without showing the user a file limit and just send the 4 images directly.

### MVC

```
if(image.Length > 0)
        {

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/products/" + uid)))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/products/") + uid);
            }


            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/products/" + uid + "/" + pid)))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/products/") + uid + "/" + pid);
            }
            string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/products/" + uid + "/" + pid), guid + "" + ".jpg");

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a Image you can upload it to a Cloud Database like Firestore or Amazon S3 or whatever and then you send the link instead of the bytes!

Answer (score 0):

*Is it a good idea to show file limit to user?* Yes it is. Better than errors popping up for them.

*Why is it not working for larger than 3MB images?* Well, if you look at the Microsoft docs, your Convert.FromBase64String method puts the data into an unsigned 8bit integer array. An unsigned int maxes out at 4.29 Million, so because you have base64 encoded, your image is actually 33% bigger, because it has a ratio of 4:3 when you base64 encode.

[Convert.FromBase64String(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=netframework-4.8)

[Base64 Padding file size increases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding)

Thus, you cant upload anything bigger than ~3MB.

*How do other companies do multi file upload?* Well they just call the same file upload endpoint, asynchronously for each file. So if you send 4 files, it will make 4 requests at the same time, and these requests will slowly upload the image (you can usually see each files individual progress bar indicator).